# Using jquery to change div content in a php loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, loops, foreach

I need to change the html in a div without page refreshing while php runs a foreach statement, i think this is possible with jquery, but i'm not sure i'm doing the correct way to achieve this. This is the code i have at the moment.

```
$filename = "entries.csv";
$topic = $_GET['q'];
$file = new SplFileObject($filename, 'w');
$sentences = explode(".", getResultsPage(getBingLink($topic)));

$file->fputcsv(array("Topic", "Sentence", "Word", "Tag"));

foreach($sentences as $sentence){
?>

<script>
    $("#view").html('<?php echo $sentence; ?>');
</script>

<?php
    if(preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9òàùèìé\s\?\!\,\-]*$/",$sentence)){

        $words = $pos->tag(explode(" ", $sentence));

        foreach($words as $word){
            $file->fputcsv(array($topic, $sentence, $word[0], $word[1]));
        }

    }
}
```

because it only prints the script when the page is loaded. Any useful hints or advices are greatly appreciated. Thanx.

Comment: what way do you want to change the div? adding nodes, remove it?

Comment: Hello Jose! Thank you for the quick response. I would like to replace the content of the div with the jquery .html() function. The sentences should display while the php foreach is running.

Comment: the way you are thinking is not possible, the php code run at the server before being render in your browser, so when your loop has ended up you're not able to run Javascript code and when your code is render at your browser you have no control over PHP code, you must achieve through only jQuery

Comment: You do realise that PHP runs on the server AND NOT on the browser dont you. So PHP runs builds a page, Sends the page to the browser, Once the browser recieved the page PHP is done. In the Browser javascript can then run.

Comment: There really has no way to do it, even with ajax?

Comment: Yes, you can do it with ajax. There are lots of examples of ajax that you can draw from.

Comment: For use cases like this the best approach is that you implement only an API endpoint in PHP what provide the actual list of data in a consumable format like JSON.

You can acquire this JSON via AJAX from the browser and do the (re)population of your list with jQuery.